# ActionScript 3 - getChildByName in nested movieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, nested, movieclip

There are 3 nested movieClips with instance names of A, B, C.

So C contains B, and B contains A, and A contains a `textField`.

How can I solve this:

```
C.B.A.txtField.text = "hello"; // WORKS

C.B.getChildByName("A").txtField.text = "hello"; // WORKS

C.getChildByName("B").A.txtField.text = "hello"; // DOESN't WORK!
C.getChildByName("B").getChildByName("A").txtField.text = "hello"; // ALSO DOESN't WORK!
```

Please let me know if you can think of any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
C["B"]["A"].txtField.text = "Jackpot!"
```